Gmail Phishing Links Screening
I'm testing a scenario where I send an email containing malicious and phishing links in the body to an inbox. However, the email does not reach the inbox and cannot be found in the spam folder either.
For reference, I've taken the links from openphish.com. What could be the exact reason for this? Is there a way to retrieve these emails?
